# Direct limit of the finite product of vector spaces

Tags: vector-spaces, commutative-algebra, category-theory

Let $I$ be an infinite set and {$E_i: i\in I$} be a family of vector spaces. For each $i\in I$, let $b_i \in E_i$ be a fixed non zero element.

For a finite subset $J$ of $I$, let $∏_{i \in J} E_i$ be the finite product of the $E_i$ and for $J \subset K$, define the connecting map ${\varphi}_{KJ}:∏_{i \in J} E_i \to ∏_{i \in K} E_i$ such that

${\varphi}_{KJ} ((x_i)_{i\in J})= (y_i)_{i \in K}$, where $y_i= x_i$ if $i \in J$ and $y_i = b_i$ if $i \in K-J$.

Then clearly, $(∏_{i \in J} E_i, {\varphi}_{KJ})_{ J \subset K \subset I}$ is a directed system of vector spaces therefore its direct limit exists. Can anybody tell me how the direct limit will look like?

Comment: This is not a direct system of vector spaces, unless each $b_i=0$, as your maps are not even group homomorphisms otherwise. The word “clearly” has, incidentally, no legitimate use in writing for a broad mathematical audience.

Comment: @KevinCarlson I see!, Okay if all the $b_i$'s are zero than in that case the direct limit is equal to the direct sum?

Comment: Yes, precisely.